# Value error while tryin IF condition for creating new column in python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, valueerror

I am trying to create a new column basis the condition below which I have passed in the if statement. I end up getting an error -**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()**

Below is the code:

```
if (concat_2020['Final RP_date']> concat_2020['R&P date_planner']):

    concat_2020['RP status'] = True

else:
    concat_2020['RP status'] = False
```

Comment: Use `concat_2020['RP status'] = concat_2020['Final RP_date']> concat_2020['R&P date_planner']`

Comment: If you search for your error message you'll find dozens of similar questions.